# replicate directory structre with 100k files to tens of windows machines

Tags: windows, replication

I have a directory structure with thousands of directories and around 100k files. (Actually it is a large java project's source tree).  I have to replicate this to 10-20  windows machines.

What I do today is one of the options in [Options for continuous one-way replication of tens of millions of files on Windows Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/200412/options-for-continuous-one-way-replication-of-tens-of-millions-of-files-on-windo) -- rsync.

I share the source directory on the master. This is mapped on all destinations machines. Then use rsync ( from a cygwin installation ) I to copy files over. The copying took 30 minutes. The process slows down as number of salves increases.
[image]
I hope there is some better solution. What is it?

Comment: Tried DFS? In general, though, this is a bad idea - use a version control mechanism for an authoritative master, pull from there via script. Otherwise machines may just get inconsistent sources at times.

Comment: @TomTom: that is fine. The what master has is a stable copy. Does not change unless triggered a by special job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any reason not to use Robocopy on the destination machines, with /MIR*. It's very good at handling large amounts of files and will only copy changed files.

Be sure to read all of the options and reduce the maximum retries and wait time.

It won't 've continuous though, you would need some kind of task.

*Apart from it being a hacky solution overall. Can you not use Git?